# Enum property in DTO is generated as string in OpenAPI specification

Tags: asp.net, swagger-ui, nswag

**Problem Description**

I'm utilizing NSwag to generate the OpenAPI specification for my API. The project I'm currently engaged with was initially constructed using ASP.NET 5.0, and recently I made the decision to upgrade it to ASP.NET 8.0. Following the upgrade of all associated libraries, I promptly encountered an issue with one of the endpoints.

This specific endpoint is designed to accept a DTO containing an `IFormFile` and an enumeration property named `FileType`. In the controller code, the DTO parameter containing both these properties is annotated with the `[FromForm]` attribute. However, upon transitioning to ASP.NET 8.0, I observed that this enum property is generated as an integer, whereas in ASP.NET 5.0 it behaved differently.
[image]

The OpenAPI specification describes `FileType` as integer type and also generates `enum` and `x-enumNames` attributes:
[image]

[image]

After I migrated project to ASP.NET 8.0 the enum property suddenly became string and `enum` and `x-enumNames` don't get generated anymore:
[image]
[image]

**Diving Deeper**

I spent some time digging into NSwag issues trying to find a solution, but unfortunately, I didn't find anything useful. So, I decided to do some debugging. Turns out, NSwag uses the ASP.NET implementation of `IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` and `IApiDescriptionProvider` to describe the API.

After looking into it further, I noticed something interesting. The `ApiDescription` object contains a bunch of `ApiParameterDescription` instances that describe the API parameters. What caught my attention was the difference in the `Type` property between ASP.NET 5.0 and 8.0. In the older version, it showed the enum type like `FileType`, but in the newer one, it just said `string`.

As I kept digging, I found out that the `DefaultApiDescriptionProvider.CreateResult` method is where things differ. Let me break down the changes in this method below:

**.net 5.0**

```
    private ApiParameterDescription CreateResult(
        ApiParameterDescriptionContext bindingContext,
        BindingSource source,
        string containerName)
    {
        return new ApiParameterDescription()
        {
            ...
            Type = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelType,
            ...
        };
    }
```

**.net 8.0**

```
    private ApiParameterDescription CreateResult(
        ApiParameterDescriptionContext bindingContext,
        BindingSource source,
        string containerName)
    {
        return new ApiParameterDescription()
        {
            ...
            Type = GetModelType(bindingContext.ModelMetadata),
            ...
        };
    }
    
    private static Type GetModelType(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        // IsParseableType || IsConvertibleType
        if (!metadata.IsComplexType)
        {
            return EndpointModelMetadata.GetDisplayType(metadata.ModelType);
        }

        return metadata.ModelType;
    }

    public static Type GetDisplayType(Type type)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
        return underlyingType.IsPrimitive
            // Those additional types have TypeConverter or TryParse and are not primitives
            // but should not be considered string in the metadata
            || underlyingType == typeof(DateTime)
            || underlyingType == typeof(DateTimeOffset)
            || underlyingType == typeof(DateOnly)
            || underlyingType == typeof(TimeOnly)
            || underlyingType == typeof(TimeSpan)
            || underlyingType == typeof(decimal)
            || underlyingType == typeof(Guid)
            || underlyingType == typeof(Uri) ? type : typeof(string);
    }
```

As it can be seen, things have changed in the implementation, especially in .NET 8.0, where any enum is now treated as a string parameter. But I really need to keep this parameter as an `integer` because switching it to a `string` would mess up my API and cause problems. So, if you've got any ideas on how to deal with this, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by providing a custom implementation of the `IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` where I adjusted the code of the `GetCollection` method:

```
    var context = new ApiDescriptionProviderContext(actionDescriptors.Items);

    foreach (var provider in _apiDescriptionProviders)
    {
        provider.OnProvidersExecuting(context);
    }

    // Added this block to change the parameter type for enumeration parameters back to their original type
    foreach (var param in context.Results.SelectMany(r => r.ParameterDescriptions))
    {
        if (param.ModelMetadata.ModelType.IsEnum)
        {
            param.Type = param.ModelMetadata.ModelType;
        }
    }

    for (var i = _apiDescriptionProviders.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        _apiDescriptionProviders[i].OnProvidersExecuted(context);
    }

    var groups = context.Results
        .GroupBy(d => d.GroupName)
        .Select(g => new ApiDescriptionGroup(g.Key, g.ToArray()))
        .ToArray();

    return new ApiDescriptionGroupCollection(groups, actionDescriptors.Version);
```